# Root CA on Apple Watch / watchOS

Tags: apple-watch, certificate

How can I install my own custom Root CA on an Apple Watch?

I know how to do it on iOS/iPad OS (→ I use Apple Configurator 2) and I also know how to do it for macOS as well as for Firefox.

However, I am not succeeding with the watch.